# Good Combat Positions

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I want to find good holdout locations for fighting the cops. Locations that have good cover, good perspective on all approaches, and bonus points for being physically unattainable by the cops (if they're too stupid to climb stairs, ladders, etc.)

I've found a few that are pretty good. Right now I'm using this bland cement tower in Paleto Bay, right behind the Ammu-Nation. It's up a few flights of stairs, so they can't get to me, but I'm exposed from a few different directions.

Has anyone been experimenting with good "crow's nests" like I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the entrance to the subway construction site located under the overpass - it's a construction tunnel; a rough dirt ramp leading down underground. Police will only enter from the tunnel mouth and never come up from the subway side.

I tend to crash a few cars into the tunnel mouth which wind up blowing up. It's not a sure fire way to block the police, but if you take cover behind an upright girder bracing the wall just down the slope, you have an excellent spot to shoot them as they come down.

You can try the same thing at the opposite end - it opens into the storm drains but the entrance is under a raised bridge which gives the police excellent firing position on you, as the tunnel mouth there is very wide open. You can however shoot down helicopters from here with the high end sniper rifle.

When you want to lose your stars, it's almost trivial to run down into the subway and they will quickly lose sight of you.